# Converting date in R with as.POSIXct() returns NA

Tags: r, date, time

I am working through the book 'R for dummies', 2nd Edition, John Wiley & Sons, Inc.
In chapter 6 you try adding time information into the vector but the shown code is not working:

Book:

```
apollo <- "July 20, 1969, 20:17:39"
apollo.fmt <- "%B %d, %Y, %H:%M:%S"
xct <- as.POSIXct(apollo, format = apollo.fmt, tz = "UTC")
xct
#> [1] "1969-07-20 20:17:39 UTC"
```

My try:

```
apollo <- "July 20, 1969, 20:17:39"
apollo.fmt <- "%B %d, %Y, %H:%M:%S"
xct <- as.POSIXct(apollo, format = apollo.fmt, tz = "UTC")
xct
#> [1] NA
```

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong, and what should be the right code?

Comment: Working fine for me. Restart your R session and run your code.

Comment: @BappaDas Probably a locale issue, mine is not a English locale and the result is `NA`. Try to see what `Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")` returns. The month name needs to be changed?

Comment: This results in: "Dutch_Netherlands.1252"
However all other date- and time-related examples are working, so I do not really see why this could be an issue.

Comment: @EzraSQL do the other examples have full English month names? Maybe try changing "July" to "Juli" if you're in a Dutch locale?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a locale problem, months in your language have other names than in English (for [`%B`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html) in date format), that's why it fails. It simply cannot recognize "July" in `apollo` string as a month, because it searches for month names in your language.

Try to set English locale for dates and times by running:

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_TIME", locale = "English")
```

or set English locale for all categories (monetary, numeric etc.):

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "English")
```

For details, see [`Sys.setlocale()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/locales.html)).

See this example (my default locale is Czech, so your code returns `NA` in my case as well):

```r
apollo <- "July 20, 1969, 20:17:39"
apollo.fmt <- "%B %d, %Y, %H:%M:%S"
xct <- as.POSIXct(apollo, format = apollo.fmt, tz = "UTC")
xct
#> [1] NA

Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_TIME", locale = "English")
#> [1] "English_United States.1252"

apollo <- "July 20, 1969, 20:17:39"
apollo.fmt <- "%B %d, %Y, %H:%M:%S"
xct <- as.POSIXct(apollo, format = apollo.fmt, tz = "UTC")
xct
#> [1] "1969-07-20 20:17:39 UTC"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>